# Gradle start scripts env

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

In gradle run task I have info about lib path:

```
run {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", "lib/native"
}
```

Is it possible to add the same variable to some gradle task that will include variable to the bin scripts, for now I have to put them manualy but I would like to automate this with gradle:

```
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/***.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/***.jar: ...
>>> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$APP_HOME/lib
```

Comment: If your scripts are not autogenerated, then you can set a placeholder in it and create a custom task, may be running as doLast or a separate one, which will replace the placeholders in your final script version with propery values.

Comment: This is one possible solution, but its a shame that this is not in gradle by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some text, such as `MY_APP_HOME`, to define `java.library.path` in JVM arguments:

`applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Djava.library.path=MY_APP_HOMElib/native']`

And then substitute it by start scripts `APP_HOME` variable in each script:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace('MY_APP_HOME', '\$APP_HOME/')
        windowsScript.text = windowsScript.text.replace('MY_APP_HOME', '%APP_HOME%\\')
    }
}
```